# {site_url} global variable not outputting in php header redirect

Tags: templates, structure, redirects, global-variables

Trying to create the following redirect template for some structure pages, however the url is outputting like this `http://example.com/{site_url}#section`. Any idea why `{site_url}` variable isn't working? And/or any idea how to resolve issue. Thanks in advance.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="pages"}
    <?php
        header( "Location: {site_url}#{homepage_section}" );
        exit;
    ?>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have PHP set to **input** on this template. That means that that something like:

```
<?php
    $test = "{site_url}";
?>
```

Causes the template parsing engine to `eval` the raw PHP code before replacing `{site_url}` with the actual site URL. You need to set PHP to **output** for this template, which means that EE template tags get parsed **FIRST**, then it `eval`s the PHP code, meaning the above will look like this by the time the raw PHP gets executed:

```
<?php
    $test = "http://www.domain.com";
?>
```

Soooo yeah. FYI, if you have PHP on that template in other places, switching from input to output could definitely break things.

**Edit**

Wait.. so one EE tag is getting parsed, but the other isn't?

Comment: The templates are already set to **output**. And yes, the `{homepage_section}` variable is parsing, but not the global variable, `{site_url}`. Any idea?